# How to check if data exists in the index/secondary key

Tags: jquery, safari, indexeddb, ydn-db

I am using ydn-db as the plugin

I have defined indexes (secondary key) and I want to check if I have any data matching for that index.

suppose I have column3 as the index and I have the value "1001"
Is there a way I can get a count/data or something if column3 has the value 1001 in it?

Comment: create a loop and iterate your data and check it; jquery/javascript doesn't contains a function for array/object called 'contains'(from what I remember)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
var kr = ydn.db.KeyRange.only(1001);
db.count('store name', 'index name', kr)
```

Or using newer syntax:

```
db.from('store name').where('index name', '=', 1001).count().done(...
```

Comment: Thanks Kyaw Tun it worked for me.Here is the link for api ref count [link](http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/query.html)